# Authorization Denied trying to access Bookings Api in Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-booking

I am trying to create an app that runs from an AWS lambda that acts as a middle man for customers wanting to sign up for a booking using Microsoft Bookings. Following the documentation I am able to generate an access token for Graph, but I get an authorization denial when I try to request information from bookings through the api.

My Code:

```
import request from "request";
import { Callback } from "./callback";

const APP_ID = process.env.BOOKINGS_APP_ID;
const APP_SECRET = process.env.BOOKINGS_API_SECRET;
const TOKEN_ENDPOINT = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.BOOKINGS_TENANT_NAME}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token`;

const requestParams = {
    client_id: APP_ID,
    client_secret: APP_SECRET,
    grant_type: "client_credentials",
    resource: "https://graph.microsoft.com",
    scope: "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
};

export default class Bookings {
    public static async listBusinesses(callback: Callback) {
        Bookings.generateAPIToken((err: string | null, data: any) => {
            const options = {
                // body: {},
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": `Bearer ${data}`,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                method: "GET",
                url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/bookingBusinesses",
            };

            console.log(data);

            return request(options, (error: string, res: any) => {
                if (error) {
                    return callback(error, {});
                }

                return callback(null, JSON.parse(res.body));
            });
        });
    }

    public static async generateAPIToken(callback: Callback) {
        request.post({ url: TOKEN_ENDPOINT, form: requestParams }, (err, res, body) => {
            if (err) {
                return callback(err, {});
            }

            return callback(null, JSON.parse(body).access_token);
        });
    }
}
```

The error that I get:

```
{
    error: {
        code: '',
        message: 'Authorization has been denied for this request.',
        innerError: {
            'request-id': '695d3f90-357d-490c-b980-4a2018dd39a5',
            date: '2020-06-08T03:21:59'
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried using the microsoft-graph-client library to access bookings but that doesn't work either. What I am doing wrong? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can see the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/bookingbusiness-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) shows the graph api(bookingBusinesses) which you want to request requires delegated type permissions and not support application type permission.

[image]

So we can not use "client_credentials" grant flow, your code shows you use "client_credentials" as the grant type. You can use "username/password" grant flow to get the access token instead. So the param you request for the access token should be like below:

```
const requestParams = {
    client_id: APP_ID,
    client_secret: APP_SECRET,
    grant_type: "password",
    scope: "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
    username: "your user name/email(like xxxxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com)",
    password: "your password"
};
```

By the way, I noticed the "TOKEN_ENDPOINT" in your code is `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.BOOKINGS_TENANT_NAME}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token` and you use both params `resource` and `scope` in `requestParams`. If we use v1 endpoint as your code, we just need to use the param `resource`. If we use v2 endpoint(`https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.BOOKINGS_TENANT_NAME}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token`), we need to use use the param `scope` instead of the param `resource`. The code I provided above use v2, so I use `scope` param and you also need to change the "TOKEN_ENDPOINT" to v2(just add a `v2.0` between the `oauth2/` and `/token`).

If you don't want to change the "TOKEN_ENDPOINT" to v2, just use the params like below:

```
const requestParams = {
    client_id: APP_ID,
    client_secret: APP_SECRET,
    grant_type: "password",
    resource: "https://graph.microsoft.com",
    username: "your user name/email(like xxxxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com)",
    password: "your password"
};
```

Hope it helps~

Comment: Thank you for helping, I am new to using any sort of Microsoft authentication, but now that I have made those changes, I get an invalid_grant error with the following description: "AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'.\r\n" Is there anyway to get around this needing to use multifactor? this function will be running headless.

Comment: @BlakeNedved It seems you enabled MFA of your azure tenant. If MFA enabled, we can't use username/password grant flow to do authentication. We can just use auth code flow to do authentication. You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) for the auth code flow and refer to this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-auth-code) to do it  by js.