# Microsoft Graph API Bookings - Authorization has been denied for this request

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-booking

I have been spending almost a day just to work out how to create a Booking using Microsoft Graph API. I'm trying this out using Postman.

**The Problem**

When I raise the below request, I get a 401 exception saying:

> Authorization has been denied for this request.

**My Application Scenario**

Basically I will need to get the authorization code without having the user signed in - it will be like service to service kind of scenario. In essence, I will have an Azure Function App API (HTTP Triggered) that communicates with MS Graph API and is called from another application hosted totally somewhere else.

**What I have done so far**

1. Here is how I have registered an app in Azure AD with the permission `Bookings.Manage.All`.
   [image]
2. And here, the Postman API to grab a token which successfully returns a token to me:
   [image]
3. And finally, another Postman API to create a booking entity using the MS Graph API which returns with the 401 exception mentioned earlier:
   [image]

Even I coded up something to experience it through the code too with the hope of finding more details but yet the same result, that is, the 401 exception. Here is a screenshot of my draft coding:

[image]

After putting the token in `jwt.io`, I realized that only the `application` permissions are shown and not the `delegate` ones, and the booking permissions are `delegate` permissions actually. I assume this has something to do with the 401 exception I'm receiving.

I've been reading through blogs everywhere but haven't managed to sort this out yet. Wondering if I'm missing something here using something wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've found out that because the `Booking` permissions are of type `delegate`, therefore, we cannot use `client_credential` flow, rather the `password` flow must be used. And a helpful answer on [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62254594/authorization-denied-trying-to-access-bookings-api-in-microsoft-graph).